# Android AdMob completely remove a InterstitialAd object

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, admob

Iam working on the ads for my project and I noticed that the ads takes quite a lot of memory. I suppose I just have to live with that. But what I don't want to live with is that I seemingly can't find a way to completely remove the ad object to get my memory back.

I am using the InterstialAds, this is my main activity:

```
public class Main extends Activity implements Constants, AdListener
{
    private GameView mGameView;
    private Activity mThis = this;
    private AdListener mThisListener = this;
    private InterstitialAd mFullScreenAd;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        mGameView = new GameView(this, getAssets()); 
        setContentView(mGameView);
    }

    public void showAd()
    {
        mFullScreenAd = new InterstitialAd(mThis, "asdasdasdasd");

        // Create ad request
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();

        // Begin loading your interstitial
        mFullScreenAd.loadAd(adRequest);

        // Set Ad Listener to use the callbacks below
        mFullScreenAd.setAdListener(mThisListener); 
    }

    public void onDismissScreen(Ad ad) 
    {
        mFullScreenAd.stopLoading();
        mFullScreenAd = null;
    }

    public void onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad ad, ErrorCode errorCode) {

    }

    public void onLeaveApplication(Ad ad) {

    }

    public void onPresentScreen(Ad ad) {

    }

    public void onReceiveAd(Ad ad) 
    {    
        if (ad == mFullScreenAd) 
            mFullScreenAd.show();
    }
}
```

So my question is: how can I completely remove the mFullScreenAd object and get the memory back?

Answer (score 0):

Once your `onDismissScreen()` method gets called, you don't have a reference to the interstitial anymore, so the garbage collector should be able to get back that memory whenever it wants.